# Strlen to strip every [x] characters

Tags: php, strlen

I'm trying strip every third character (in the example a period) below is my best guess and is close as ive gotten but im missing something, probably minor. Also would this method (if i could get it working) be better than a regex match, remove?

```
$arr = 'Ha.pp.yB.ir.th.da.y';
$strip = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($arr); $i += 2) {
$arr[$i] = $strip; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do it is:

```
<?php
$oldString = 'Ha.pp.yB.ir.th.da.y';
$newString = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($oldString ); $i++) // loop the length of the string
{
  if (($i+1) % 3 != 0) // skip every third letter
  {
    $newString .= $oldString[$i];  // build up the new string
  }
}
// $newString is HappyBirthday
echo $newString;
?>
```

Alternatively the explode() function might work, if the letter you're trying to remove is always the same one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, especially the commenting, but the output im getting with that is **a.p.B.r.h.a.** ?

Comment: Looks like my test was a bit off, I've fixed it now and you can see at http://ideone.com/da4dS

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
echo preg_replace('/(..)./', '$1', 'Ha.pp.yB.ir.th.da.y');
```

To make it general purpose:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.{2})./', '$1', $str);
```

where `2` in this context means you are keeping two characters, then discarding the next.

Comment: preg_replace('/([A-Za-z]{2})./', '$1', $str); would be more secure

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing it:

```
$old = 'Ha.pp.yB.ir.th.da.y';
$arr = str_split($old); #break string into an array

#iterate over the array, but only do it over the characters which are a
#multiple of three (remember that arrays start with 0)
for ($i = 2; $i < count($arr); $i+=2) {
    #remove current array item
    array_splice($arr, $i, 1);
}
$new = implode($arr); #join it back
```

Or, with a regular expression:

```
$old = 'Ha.pp.yB.ir.th.da.y';
$new = preg_replace('/(..)\./', '$1', $old);
#selects any two characters followed by a dot character
#alternatively, if you know that the two characters are letters,
#change the regular expression to:
/(\w{2})\./
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and a callback function. It'd look roughly like this:

```
function remove_third_char( $text ) {
    return substr( $text, 0, 2 );
}

$text = 'Ha.pp.yB.ir.th.da.y';
$new_text = str_split( $text, 3 );

$new_text = array_map( "remove_third_char", $new_text );

// do whatever you want with new array
```